# jQuery.validator webpack 2 and typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to set up the scripts of my project with webpack 2.

Currently my files are compiling but I have an issue with **jQuery-validation**

I have this error when I try to generate my file :

> ERROR in ./wwwroot/scripts/ts/core.ts (18,20): error TS2339: Property
>   'validator' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'.

Here is my import in core.ts :

```
import jQuery = require("jquery");
import "jquery-validation"
```

And my webpack config :

```
'use strict';

var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    cache: true,
    entry: {
        main: './wwwroot/scripts/ts/public/index.ts'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './wwwroot/scripts/js'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            $: 'jquery',
            jquery: 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'ts-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,

        }]

    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']

    }
};
```

I already found a lot of thing with Google, but any solution works for me, so if anyone have an idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the typings for `jquery-validation`:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery.validation
```

Comment: of course it is installed, and is not jquery.validation but jquery-validation

Comment: @OrcusZ. `@types/jquery.validation` 
is the package that contains the typings for jquery-validation library. See [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery.validation/index.d.ts). And there are no typings with the name `jquery-validation`. What typings package did you install?

Comment: sorry my fault, I confused with the npm package. My installed types ( under @types folder ) are : **jquery, jquery-validation-unobtrusive, jquery.validation**

Comment: @OrcusZ If you have the types installed then post a reproducible example. A plunkr would help. As of now it is hard to see what is wrong.

Comment: damn... I should import jquery-calidation instead of jquery.validation in my typescript file

Comment: But you are already importing `jquery-validation` in you core.ts file (as mentioned in the question). What am I missing?

Comment: I put the correct import in the post but not on my code... I did it at midnight... Just tired sorry and thanks for your time